# What information does a wireless access point have about connected devices?

Tags: network, wifi, wireless, mac-address

Which information about a connected device leaks to the access point it is connected to? What's the minimum amount of information that must be supplied to successfully connect, apart from the password?

So far, I'm only able to see reason for:

- hostname
- physical address
- IP address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot more of information the access point has about any connected device. At least:

- the protocol used
- some kind of signal strengh
- the current key for encryption
- some history for packet delivery
- the data sent and received as the first hop of the device to the network
- time of the connection

Depending on the time constraints and the bookkeeping, also enough data to roughly guess the position of the device.

There might be even more data available; I would have to take a look at the protocol definitions to see what else is shared.

Comment: thanks for the answer but can AP have that any other info like mac address or host name that can't be change and every time we connect to AP and it's like this is the person that connected before.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The physical address and hostname are in the question already. They by the way can easily be spoofed.

Comment: sorry for bad context. i just want to know what things could use to block you from an AP like mac address filters. please.

Comment: There is no way I know of to block access except using a secure passphrase. MAC-Addresses can easily be spoofed, as can the host name and several other things. A consumer grade access point might offer such filters, albeit they are useless. Other information on the protocol level might allow educated guesses about the identity of the device trying to connect, but that is no practical way for several reasons: it's not fail safe, it's not accurate and it's not easy to implement.